# MediaWiki installation issue - port problems

Tags: database, postgresql, mediawiki, wiki

I am trying to install MediaWiki version 1.31 localy and I have run into some issues that I cant get past by. Mainly when I input datatabe connection (I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL database) information it returns this error. [image]

Thing is the port I am trying to connect is 5433 not 5432, also the names "template1" and "postgres" are not included in my input trough the dialogue screen - I dont know where they came from. "test1" is the name of the database I am trying to  connect to.
Any help or advice how to get trough this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the port you specify is not used while setting up the database schema in the first place is a long-standing [known bug](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T245387).  One workaround is to run your database on the default port until you have wiki set up, then change it back to the port you want.

In order to create a new database, you need to connect to an existing database in the same cluster.  'template1' and 'postgres' are pre-existing databases (usually created at the time the cluster was created) commonly used to connect to in order to create a new database.  These names are "well-known", you don't need to specify them.